# How do I realistically assess the risk of side effects with a drug?

Tags: risks, side-effects

A consultant I saw this week prescribed an additional medication (Gabapentin Milpharm 100mg). The idea being to reduce the sensitivity of my nerves (and thus, I guess, not feel so much pain). Which I am fine with.

However, there is a scary long list of symptoms which says "fewer than 1 in 10 experienced these". They range from funny (flatulence) to redundant (Back Pain) to weird (Sudden Anger at others) and worse (impotence, vertigo, etc.)

How do I get an accurate picture of my actual risk, here?

Is that less than 10% of the population a total for all symptoms, for "at least one" or for each of them?

How do I assess the information I have at hand?